# Redefinition error with header files - cpp

Tags: c++, oop, templates, header-files

I have a template functions defined in a header file under a namespace. When I include this header in two source file in the same project. I don't get redefinition error.

```
/* template.h */
namespace x 
{
   template<typename T>
   function(t)
   {
       /* implementation */
   }
}

/*test.cpp*/
#include "template.h"

/* test2.cpp */
#inlcude "template.h"
```

In the above case I don't get any redefinition error. .Why I am not receiving any error?

Comment: That's because you don't define a *function* in your header file, you define a function *template*. I suggest you read e.g. [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for some more information.

Comment: i dont understand - are you asking WHY you are NOT getting error? or what? Since header file included once in each cpp file, there is no redefinition - each cpp sees this header only once, so it is ok....

Comment: What happens when I include template.h in multiple source files @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: it is ok to include header file to several source file. Each source file will get its own implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because implicit template instantiations behave as if they were implicitly `inline`: all of them are consolidated into a single one at link-time.

Answer (score 0):

Define the Header fine in the inner header file, when you include the inner header file to outer file all the headers will be included.

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

/* ... Declarations etc here ... */

#endif
```